# Applying themes programatically in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, themes, application-settings

Does anyone know what is best way to implement setting concept for changing themes throughout the app including the font colour, font family name and font Size in iOS 7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a CSS type Style Sheet class in your code where you define all your font type, colours, etc. using macros and use those macros for setting those fields at the required places. When the user goes to the **settings** page and chooses a different theme, you just need to handle those macros. Hope it helps.

Comment: You could consider upvoting or accepting an answer if you find it useful. It helps people who search later to find a definitive and better quality answer. Anyways, happy to help. :)